# How to change the color of a PShape on key press?

Tags: colors, processing

I am trying to change the color of a PShape when I press a key, as a marker that that key is pressed. Is there a way that I can do this without redefining the PShape using `beginShape()` and `endShape()` with a new fill every time?

Here is an example of what I am attempting to do:

```
PShape s;

void setup() {
  size(100,100);
  s = createShape(RECT,25,25,50,50);
  s.setFill(color(75,183,19));
  
  shape(s);
}

void draw() {
  if(keyPressed == true) {
    if(key == 'w') {
      s.setFill(color(217,93,47));
    }
  }
}
```

the `setFill()` function works before I actually put the shape into the window, but it won't in the `draw()` function. I have also tried using `fill()`.

I have also tried using `disableStyle()` when declaring the shape and changing the fill before redrawing the shape:

```
PShape s;

void setup() {
  size(100,100);
  shape();
  fill(75,183,19);
  
  shape(s);
}

void draw() {
  if(keyPressed == true) {
    if(key == 'w') {
      fill(217,93,47);
      shape();
    }
  }
}

void shape() {
  s = createShape(RECT,25,25,50,50);
  s.disableStyle();
}
```

This also doesn't work, the shape just stays as the first color. Is there any function I am missing which will help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will change the color of a PShape square each time a designated key is pressed:

```
PShape s;
color chosenColor;

void setup() {
  size(100,100);
  chosenColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
}

void draw() {
  myShape();
}

void myShape() {
  s = createShape(RECT,25,25,50,50);
  s.setFill(chosenColor);
  shape(s);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'w') {
    chosenColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  }
}
```